# Read Data Firebase assign value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to assign the data I have read in the Firebase database to the values I have given in the code. The data is being read in the code I have given, but the values are not being assigned. I want to assign deviceroom1, deviceRoom2, deviceRoom3, deviceRoom4.

```
    var deviceRoom1: String = ""
    var deviceRoom2: String = ""
    var deviceRoom3: String = ""
    var deviceRoom4: String = ""
    var deviceRoom5: String = ""

 func fetchDevies(){

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(self.chip1InfoString!).child("Rooms")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if let deviceRooms1 = value?["Rooms1"] as? String  {
                self.deviceRoom1 = deviceRooms1

            }
            if let deviceRooms2 = value?["Rooms2"] as? String {
                self.deviceRoom2 = deviceRooms2

            }
            if let deviceRooms3 = value?["Rooms3"] as? String {
                self.deviceRoom3 = deviceRooms3

            }
            if let deviceRooms4 = value?["Rooms4"] as? String {
                self.deviceRoom4 = deviceRooms4

            }
            if let deviceRooms5 = value?["Rooms5"] as? String {
                self.deviceRoom5 = deviceRooms5

            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

                let items = [deviceRoom1, deviceRoom2, deviceRoom3, deviceRoom4, deviceRoom5]
```

Comment: if you print(value), does it look like what you expect? Also, could you please show the data structure of the section of your database that you're trying to retrieve from?

Comment: It sees the data I expect, draws the data I want, but can not assign the string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is that Firebase is asynchronous so you need to give Firebase time to fetch and return the requested data. i.e. the data is only valid within the closure.

Your code is assigning values with *let items = ...* outside the closure and that code will execute way before the data is returned.  Move the assignment inside like closure like this (code is shortened for brevity)

```
func fetchDevies() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("some_node").child("Rooms")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        if let deviceRooms1 = value?["Rooms1"] as? String  {
            self.deviceRoom1 = deviceRooms1
        }
        .
        .
        .
        let items = [self.deviceRoom1, self.deviceRoom2, self.deviceRoom3, self.deviceRoom4, self.deviceRoom5]
        print(items)
    })

    //code here will run before Firebase has returned data and populated the vars
```

Also, be careful with var names. If you are accessing a class var, always refer to it with self. like self.deviceRoom1