# Handling Firebase Auth error in SwiftUI Combine app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui, combine

I have an app where users can sign up and login using Firebase. However, I can not seem to alert the user of any errors in the view.

First we have a **UserStore** which is a `ObservableObject` and is initialised as an `EnvironmentObject` when setting up the view in the `SceneDelegate`.

```
let appView = AppView().environmentObject(userStore)

  if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: appView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Then we sign up or login to the View like so.

**In View**

```
self.userStore.logIn(email: self.email, password: self.password)
self.isLoggingIn = true

if self.userStore.failedToLogin {
   self.isLoggingIn = false
   self.alertTitle = "There seems to be a problem"
   self.alertBody = self.userStore.errorMessage
   self.showingAlert = true
}
```

Then the actual method should update the UserStore property values which then update the view and display an alert, however, this is not the case.

**SignIn**

```
// Session Properties
@Published var isLoggedIn = false {didSet{didChange.send() }}
@Published var isNewUser = false {didSet{didChange.send() }}
@Published var failedToCreateAccount = false {didSet{didChange.send() }}
@Published var failedToLogin = false {didSet{didChange.send() }}
@Published var errorMessage = "" {didSet{didChange.send() }}

init () {
  handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    if let user = user {
      self.session = user
      self.isLoggedIn = true
      //Change isNewUser is user document exists?
   } else {
      self.session = nil
      self.isLoggedIn = false
    }
  }
}

func logIn(email: String, password: String) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] user, error in

        print("Signed In")

        if(error != nil) {
            print("Failed to login")

            self!.failedToLogin = true
            self!.errorMessage = ("\(String(describing: error))")
            print(error!)
            return
        } else if error == nil {
            print("Success Logging In")

        }
    }
}
```

The AppView determines which view is loaded depending if the user is logged in.

**AppView**

```
        if !userStore.isLoggedIn {
            LoginView().transition(.opacity)
        }

        if userStore.isLoggedIn  {
            ContentView().transition(.opacity)
        }
```

Atm error messages are not shown; the login view is also shown shortly before the main view.

How can I correctly display error messages in the view ?

Comment: The issues seems to be that `userStore.login` is an asynchronous process. I.e. the call to `if self.userStore.failedToLogin` is executed before `userStore.login` returns. Thus, `userStore.failedToLogin` is still `false`, and the code in the conditional statement will never be executed.

There are two ways around this:

1. Implement a trailing closure on `userStore.logIn`, and move the code which displays the error into the closure
2. Make `userStore.failedToLogin` a publisher and subscribe the visibility of your alert to it

Comment: @PeterFriese 100% on point comment. I would post that as an answer. OP - This line `self.isLoggingIn = true` and the code following it will execute *before* the user gets logged in - code is faster than the internet and you need to execute the next 'step' from within the Firebase signIn closure. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025373/read-data-firebase-assign-value/56062986#56062986) for additional reading

Comment: pod 'CombineFirebase/Auth' will hugely simplify your problem. Instead of callback, you can simply use combine publisher pattern and use combine powerful operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase APIs are asynchronous, simply because they access a remote system, across the internet, which takes a little time. The same applies for accessing the local disk, by the way. This [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93) explains this in more detail.

Consequently, `userStore.login` is an asynchronous process. I.e. the call to `if self.userStore.failedToLogin` is executed before `userStore.login` returns. Thus, `userStore.failedToLogin` is still `false`, and the code in the conditional statement will never be executed.

There are two ways around this:

1. Implement a trailing closure on `userStore.logIn`, and move the code which displays the error into the closure
2. Make `userStore.failedToLogin` a publisher and subscribe the visibility of your alert to it

Comment: Thank you soo much! Yeah it's pretty obvious now. Also I read your Medium post about Firebase and SwiftUI, Combine; any idea when part 3 with Apple Sign in will be out ? As that is what I am working on now..

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @RileyDev! Working on part 3 as we speak, hope to get it out next week!

Comment: Part 3 of the series @RileyDev asked about is now available at https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part3/

Answer (score 0):

Use Combine Firebase: https://github.com/rever-ai/CombineFirebase

This is combine-swiftui wrapper around firebase api, so you can use swift-ui publisher pattern for firebase.