# Fetch document only once when Firestore has updated

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a tableView that bring all documents from Firestore collection and i want to fetch the last document only once when it is added to the Firestore after user refresh the tableView and after that I want to remove the listener so when the user refresh the tableView it only fetch document once , i used detach listener [from the documentation here][1] but it didn't work

```
func updatedFireStoredata() {
    
    
    let listener =  Firestore.firestore().collection("collection1").order(by: "date").limit(toLast: 1).addSnapshotListener() { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                
                let data = diff.document.data()
    
                self.amount.append(data["amount"] as? String ?? "")
                
                print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    table2.reloadData()
    listener.remove()
}
```

Comment: This *every time the user refresh the tableView* is called polling and it's probably not necessary (and can be annoying to the user). You should set up a *listener* aka *observer* on your firebase so firebase will notify your app when there is updated data.

Comment: @Jay user should refresh the tableView to show the new document that retrieved , the problem here is when the user refresh the tableView the application retrieve documents every time the user refresh the table view and i want to retrieve it only one time if the user refresh the tableView .

Comment: @Jay i updated my question , please can you check it

Comment: The approach is the issue. You should not require the user to keep pressing refresh to get updated data. That should happen automatically and the user should always have current data with no interaction. Totally remove `listener.remove()` and move `table2.reloadData()` inside the Firebase closure  That way when new data is added, your app will automatically receive it and update the table. Note that Firebase is asynchronous - refreshing the tableView *outside* of (after) the closure will execute *before* the code in the closure so it needs to be inside.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to only call once to retrieve this document, I would consider using the offline persistence that is built in to the SDK. You will need to request the document once with offline persistence enabled, but after that call you can request this data from that local cache.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access

Alternatively you could store the document locally, and not include it in reload.

If it is the case that this data does change, just not as often as every refresh, it may make sense to move this to an eventing model. You can use firestore watch/listen to monitor that query and get update callbacks as needed. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: i tried it but it retrieve the data many times , please help i want to retrieve the new data only one time if the tableView is reloaded, i did alot of research but i didn't find any way so, please help me with this and i will appreciate your help

Comment: The way your code is authored you are asking to reload the data on refresh. I see two paths forward:
1) This data doesn't change, you just need it once. The solution to this is either to store the document and not refresh it as part of reload as authored.

2) The data does change, but maybe not frequently. You want the updates, but the refresh is far too often. Consider using a Firestore Watch/Listener. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: Also i tried to use listener and the same problem i face which is it reload the data many times :(

Comment: Were you by chance trying to restart the listener on refresh in that case? I would not expect that to cause frequent updates.

Comment: the problem is it retrieve the data but it cannot limit it to the last one

Comment: I noticed your query has two limit clauses. Can you try removing the second (.limit(toLast: 1).limit(to: 1).getDocuments() => .limit(toLast: 1).getDocuments())

Comment: please help me.

Comment: @mohammed I am not sure what offline persistence (mentioned in this answer) has to do with getting data from Firebase one time. The two are totally unrelated. See my comment to your question as polling or storing the data locally is not needed. However the second suggestion in this answer is spot on; a listener is the way to go.

Comment: As you can disable network for regions, offline persistence is a local cache. This would prevent more than one lookup against the firestore service.

It is still unclear if the data is changing (listener) or it doesn't change (store/cache locally).

I suspect using a listener is the way forward but it is hard to be certain from the question.

Comment: @ChrisWilcox i updated my question , please can you check it

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things

First, requiring a user to keep clicking refresh to get the current data is not a good experience. The data should be presented to the user automatically without interaction

Second, Firebase is asynchronous - code outside the Firebase closure will execute before the data in the closure. See my answer [Firebase is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025373/read-data-firebase-assign-value/56062986#56062986) <- that's for the Realtime Database but the concept applies to asynchronous functions in general.

To fix both issues here's updated code

```
func updatedFireStoredata() {
    let listener =  Firestore.firestore().collection("collection1").order(by: "date").limit(toLast: 1).addSnapshotListener() { querySnapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
            if (diff.type == .added) {
                
                let data = diff.document.data()
    
                self.amount.append(data["amount"] as? String ?? "")
                
                print("New city: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
            
        }
        table2.reloadData()  //needs to be inside the closure
    }
}
```

I moved the tableView reload inside the closure so it executes when new data arrives and then removed the code to remove the listener so your tableView will update with new data.

I also updated the error handler to handle an actual error code.

One thing you will want to do is to keep track of what the user has selected is is looking at - you don't want a selected item, for example, to un-select if other data is added which is what will happen when the tableView reloads.