# SwiftUI App can't get data from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I will start by explaining with words, then I will explain with code below. Here we go.

I have a struct 'User' that I use in my app. It has important data like username, email, and profileImageUrl. To access a list of users, I need to request a list of users from Firestore. But when I do this, it returns an empty array.

EXCEPT right after I log in. If I check the Users array before I log in, it's empty. If I check the users array after I log in, it's empty. But if I print it inside the .onAppear of the main content view that loads, it prints the true array of users.

I also notice that my program never thinks I'm the current user, even if I am. Each instance of User has a property `isCurrentUser: Bool` that is supposed to check if the user that is currently logged in is the same user in that instance. But they all appear as false.

It seems to me that the program thinks I'm not logged in, and will only let me pull data from the server if I'm logged in. Even though I changed my Firestore and Firebase Storage rules to allow me to read and write even if I'm not logged in.

Here are important snippets of code.

User struct

```
struct User : Identifiable {
    let id : String
    let username : String
    let profileImageUrl : String
    let email : String
    let isCurrentUser: Bool
    init (dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.isCurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == self.id
    }
}
```

notice the `self.isCurrentUser` code. I'm thinking maybe this code isn't working, or that  self.id isn't working properly.

I also receive these two errors whenever I unsuccessfully fetch from the Users array.

```
2021-02-24 21:00:50.172361-0800 Council[38163:1564633] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
```

```
2021-02-24 21:00:52.168254-0800 Council[38163:1564630] [connection] nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C1] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com:443
```

So please share any knowledge you have this problem is killing me i have to finish this app in time and now I am not able to work due to this bug

Here is my main ContentView that shows login screen if a user isn't logged in, but shows the homepage if a user is logged in. I called an instance of `SearchViewModel()` to test if I could print SearchViewModel().users. This is the view in which I can get the users array to print, but only right after I log in. If I attempt to print it on a subsequent page, it'll be the same empty array.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navBarHidden: Bool = true
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel : AuthViewModel
    @ObservedObject var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            if viewModel.userSession != nil{
                NavigationView{

                    
                    TabView{
                        FeedView(navBarHidden: $navBarHidden)
                            .navigationBarHidden(self.navBarHidden)
                            .tabItem{
                                Image(systemName: "house")
                                Text("For You")
                            }
                        Text("Random")
                            .tabItem{
                                Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle")
                                Text("Random")
                            }
                        SearchView()
                            .tabItem {
                                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                Text("Search")
                            }
                            .navigationBarHidden(true)

                    }
                    .accentColor(.black)
                    .onAppear() {
                        searchViewModel.fetchUsers()
                        print(searchViewModel.users)
                        
                        }
                }

            } else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

More code: Here is my User struct

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct User : Identifiable {
    let id : String
    let username : String
    let profileImageUrl : String
    let email : String
    let isCurrentUser: Bool
    init (dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
        self.isCurrentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == self.id
    }
}
```

Here is the file for the ViewModel that fetches the users

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    init() {
        fetchUsers()
        print("usersFetched")
    }
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {return}
            
            documents.forEach{ document in
                let user = User(dictionary: document.data())
                self.users.append(user)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the ViewModel that authenticates users, creates users, and logs them in

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var isAuthenticating = false
    @Published var error: Error?
    @Published var user: User?
    
    init() {
        userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        fetchUser()
    }
    
    func login(withEmail email : String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("Failed to upload image. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            self.userSession = result?.user
            print("U logged in")
        }
    }
    
    func registerUser( email : String, password: String, username: String, profileImage: UIImage) {
        
        guard let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else {return}
        let fileName = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(fileName)
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { _, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("Failed to upload image. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            print("successful upload of photo")
            storageRef.downloadURL { url , _ in
                guard let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else {return}
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail:  email, password: password) { result, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Failed to Register. Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let user = result?.user else {return}
                    
                    let data = ["email": email,
                                "username": username.lowercased(),
                                "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl,
                                "uid": user.uid]
                    
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(user.uid).setData(data) { _ in
                        self.userSession = user
                        print("successfully uploaded user data")
                    }
                    
                    print("Successful SIgnup")
                }

            }
        }

        
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        userSession = nil
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    
    func fetchUser() {
        guard let uid = userSession?.uid else {return}
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            
            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else {return}
            let user = User(dictionary: data)
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: New possibility for an issue. When the users array successfully prints, it does so in this format:

```
MyApp.User(id: "kugrbub", username: "user1", profileImageUrl: "https://theimageurl.com", email: "ceo@violent.jewelry", isCurrentUser: false),
```

When it prints, it's in parentheses, not braces. So is this a reason why it could be failing?

Comment: I would be very surprised if the amount of code you've shown is enough for a diagnosis. At the minimum, I'd like to see where you're instantiating `User`

Comment: @jnpdx I added more code, let me know if theres any more code or information I could add in order to make the problem clearer

Comment: The answer provided by @jnpdx is spot on. But some additional reading may also help clarify what is mean by *asynchronous*. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272535/i-keep-getting-a-sigabrt-error-when-trying-to-read-my-firebase-database-and-crea/60383635#60383635) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027817/how-to-perform-an-action-only-after-data-are-downloaded-from-firebase/43029121#43029121) and maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66162801/fetch-document-only-once-when-firestore-has-updated/66186682#66186682)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I see what's going wrong. I think that you're misunderstanding what is happening with the asynchronous Firebase methods.

When you call a method like `.getDocuments` in Firebase, that method does not return instantaneously. Rather, it runs asynchronously and then calls your callback function that you provide when it's finished.

Why does this lead to the result that you're getting? In ContentView, you initialize `SearchViewModel` by calling `SearchViewModel()` to set up the property. In the `init()` of `SearchViewModel`, `fetchUsers()` is called, which populates the `users` array when it completes.

Then, once your login completes, `ContentView` switches over to your `NavigationView`/`TabView`, and `onAppear` is called. Inside, you call `fetchUsers` again, which starts running asynchronously. But, because you had already called `fetchUsers` in the `SearchViewModel` init, the array already has data in it (keep in mind that unless you explicitly sign out of Firebase, you'll still be signed in from the previous session).

So, how do you solve this?

1. Remember that all of those calls are asynchronous. Printing the arrays right after calling the fetchUsers method(s) will never get you the values you want *unless they had been populated before.
2. Restructure your app so that you can respond to the changes in the view model asynchronously. Because you have so much going on, there's not one definitive way to clean everything up. But, you can look into a couple of things:

- look up `onReceive` which you can use to tell when a single publisher on your ObservableObject has changed.
- When using Firebase, I like using `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` to respond to the auth state. That might help you start to split up your login logic.
- Instead of printing after your `fetchUsers` call, print from inside the Firebase callback functions.

A code sample for you:

```
class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        guard Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil else {
            assertionFailure("NOT SAFE TO GET USERS YET -- NOT LOGGED IN")
            return
        }
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {return}
            
            print("Received docs:")
            print(documents)
            
            documents.forEach{ document in
                let user = User(dictionary: document.data())
                self.users.append(user)
            }
            
            print("USERS:")
            print(self.users)
        }
    }
}

struct ShowUsersView: View {
    @ObservedObject var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(searchViewModel.users, id: \.id) { user in
                Text(user.username)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            print("Calling fetchUsers...")
            searchViewModel.fetchUsers()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for answering, it means a lot. I don't really understand the meaning of asynchronous. Does that mean the array is empty until I call .getDocuments and goes back empty right after? So is the array always empty because I keep calling `.getDocuments`?  And when you refer to callback functions, are you saying I should initialize the array by saying `let users : [User] = SearchViewModel().fetchUsers()` ? The end goal here is not to print the array but to be able to display all the users. For example, in a search view.

Comment: Asynchronous means that the function doesn't finish right away. Instead, it runs and calls a callback function when it's done. So, if you call an async function on line 1, line 2 will get executed next, but it doesn't mean line 1 has finished. In your view model, what you have between the curly braces starting with `snapshot, _` is your callback function. What gets called after the function actually finishes running.

Comment: In terms of when to call `getDocuments`, you should try to plan it so that you are just calling it once logged in (I gave a suggestion for how to do that in my answer). Right now, you're calling it many times, and then trying to print before it even finishes running. For the second part, no, do not try to initialize `users` by calling `fetchUsers()`. You want to call that once you're logged in and ready to get the info. Unfortunately, these are much larger programming concepts than fit well into a SO comment.

Comment: so I removed the fetchUsers from the init function of the SearchViewModel class, and I only call it once, when the main home screen appears. I even waited like 5 minutes to let it run asynchronously. But the array is still empty when I try to pull a user from it.

Comment: It's not a matter of waiting 5 minutes. It's a matter of when you "try to pull a user" from it. Where are you doing that? Did you move your print statement inside the callback function like I suggested?

Comment: yes, I am pulling a user with this method: 'UserProfileView(user: viewModel.fetchUsers()[0])'. I updated the fetchUsers function to return the users array from within itself. Also, the index out of range crash doesn't happen when I try to load UserProfileView, it happens when I try to load ChatView which contains MessageView which contains UserProfileView. So maybe Swift is checking if the index is empty before it actually fethes the users?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229215/discussion-between-jnpdx-and-cayland-boston).